# How to fit the nav bar with full page?

Tags: html, css

show the empty space, how to fit nav bar with full page?

[image]

(This is the code for nav bar )

```
        <ul type="none">
        <li> Home </li> 
        <li> News </li>
        <li> SignIn </li>
       </ul>
       <div>
```

Comment: You need to show the CSS

Comment: li
{
 float: left; width: 30%; background-color: pink; padding: 20px; color: mediumpurple; font-weight: bold; 
}

Comment: @Mohsin Ali, Have a glance at: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar_horizontal.asp. This link will guide you on how to make a good navbar in a beginner-friendly manner.  I would also recommend having a glance at their tutorials as they are beginner-friendly and well documented. NOTE: I am not in any promotive relations with W3Schools. This comment is based upon my pure opinion and experience.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your head tags, add the below code between the `<style>` and `</style>` tags (or add them in any other CSS file which is linked to the target HTML file)

```css
ul{
position: fixed; //or any other position you want. 
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
margin : 0;
}
```

Comment: li
{
 float: left; width: 30%; background-color: pink; padding: 20px; color: mediumpurple; font-weight: bold; 
}
ul{
position: absolute; //or any other position you want. 

left: 5px;
right: 20px;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;

}

Comment: Here is it's css style

Comment: @Mohsin Ali,assuming the change was dine unintentionally,  please change `left: 5px;` to `left: 0;` to achieve your desired position. Check this for more info about left position: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp

Comment: Also, have a glance at: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar_horizontal.asp. This link will guide you on how to make a good navbar in a beginner-friendly manner.  I would also recommend having a glance at their tutorials as they are beginner-friendly and well documented. NOTE: I am not in any promotive relations with W3Schools. This comment is based upon my pure opinion and experience.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `<ul>` has browser stylesheet where it already has margin/padding so do this

```
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
```

also go for wrap them all in a `<header>` tag and all the navigation items in `<nav>` tag and add css property like this

```
header{
    position:fixed;
    inset:0;
    width:100vw;
}
```

and please dont wrap header with any other element except for body,html ofcourse